# Cant get the attribute value of the order button in application dev tools(javascript)

Tags: javascript

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
  const orderButtons = document.querySelectorAll("data-order");

  orderButtons.forEach(function(button) {

    button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      const button = e.currentTarget;
      const button = button.parentNode;

      const order = {
        id: button.getAtrribute("data-order"),
        title: container.querySelector(".title").innerText,
        price: container.querySelector(".price").innerText,
        desc: container.querySelector(".desc").innerText,
      };

      localStorage.setItem("order", JSON.stringify(order));

      const url = window.location.href.replace("pies.html", "order.html");

    });
  });

});
```

Comment: The parameter name is `button` and you are creating 2 more const variables with the same name: `const button = e.currentTarget; const button = button.parentNode;`

Comment: how can i resolve that sir? sry just new here in programming

Comment: Either give them different names or just declare a single one: `const button = e.currentTarget.parentNode;`. Btw, are you sure your query selector is correct? I mean, It'll select elements with a *tag name* of `data-order`...

Comment: yeah, my bad it should be :const orderButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-order]");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mis-spell. It should be getAttribute, not getAtrribute